# Create new album in facebook using Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, upload, photos

I'm using the following code to upload a photo:

```
FB.api('/photos', 'post', {
  message: fbMessage,
  access_token: response.session.access_token,
  url: imgURL
}, function (response) {
  //do something
if (!response || response.error) {
} else {
  //do something      
}
});
```

this code will upload the photo in an album that has the name of the App,
I want to choose the album name, should I create an album and upload the photos in it and how ?